# Trying to use Electron Forge to build app for Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm developing a small, simple app on a Mac based device and have installed the Electron Forge CLI, I'm running the `make` command and then the `package` command which right now exports to a Zip which doesn't seem to be recognised by the Raspberry Pi Zero (running Raspbian OS) and I don't know why.

I've tried passing `linux` as a platform to my config, and this doesn't build either:

My config:

```
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "countdown_timer"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Where am I going wrong?

I've also tried:

> `electron-forge make --arch=linux`

But this gives me an error, what config/command do I need to run to make an app for this platform?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on the Raspberry Pi 4.

1. Copy your project to the PI
2. In the project dir run: `npm run make -- --arch=armv7l --targets=@electron-forge/maker-deb`
3. You get am installable .deb, in the project/out/make/deb/armv7l folder